# Localization of code generated natural language strings

Tags: android, localization, grammar

I'm writing an app in which I want to display a string, describing an object in my model, to the user.  I've started thinking about localization and I'm a bit stumped as to the best approach to deal with the difference in grammar between languages.

Imagine if in my model I have a verb an object and a quantity (pseudocode):

```
int _quantity = 6;
String _object = "@string/object";
String _verb = "@string/verb";
```

This should render in English as _verb + _quantity + _object (i.e. "eat 6 eggs", whereas in German it should render as _quantity + _object + _verb (i.e. "6 eggs eat" (but, obviously, using German word tokens rather than English :) ))

Is there a standard approach to this type of problem in Android?

Thanks.

Comment: I suppose there isn't. I practice not to use statements which will be created run time. Localization can be used when you have full static sentence available. Ex.: "eat 6 eggs" should be static. FYI "static" is not Java static I am referring to. Static means predefined :)

Comment: Why the downvotes?  Should I rephrase the question?

Comment: @Shrikant Please check the solution I've posted and let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've come up with a solution which, based on what I know, is the best I can find.  If anyone has a better solution, please post!

1) In strings.xml, define any bits of text needed (for me, these equated to the localised names for enumeration members and for the string used to build natural language strings (more on this in a bit))

Example:

```
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="verb_ate">ate</string>
    <string name="verb_threw">threw</string>
    ...
    <string name="modelobject_naturallanguagedescription">I {0} {1} {2}</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

2) In any enumerations, decorate them with the resource ids of the strings they are to use for display

Example:

```
public enum VerbType
    Ate(R.string.verb_ate),
    Threw(R.string.verb_threw);

    private final int _stringID;

    private VerbType(int stringID) {
        _stringID = stringID;
    }

    public int getStringID() {
        return _stringID;
    }
}
```

3) Make a helper function which will take the model object and the context and will piece together the required natural language string (using java.text.MessageFormat), plus a helper function for each enumeration:

Example (assume that ModelObject has _verb, _quantity, _object and relevant getters):

```
public static String getVerb(VerbType v, Context c) {
    return c.getResources().getString(v.getStringID());
}

public static String getNaturalLanguageString(ModelObject o, Context c) {
    MessageFormat mf = new MessageFormat(c.getResources().getString(R.string.modelobject_naturallanguagedescription);
    return mf.format(new Object[] {getVerb(o.getVerb(),c), o.getQuantity(), o.getObject()});
}
```

So, having done all of this, it's easy enough to define another strings file for a different language (German for example (I don't know German, so the language won't be correct)):

```
<resources>
    ...
    <string name="verb_ate">gegessen</string>
    <string name="verb_threw">gethrown</string>
    ...
    <string name="modelobject_naturallanguagedescription">Ich haben {1} {2} {0}</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

So, in an english locale getNaturalLanguageString might return:

```
I ate 6 eggs
```

whereas in a German locale it might return:

```
Ich haben 6 eggs gegessen
```